# Lookup field by order

Tags: python

Suppose I have a look-up list and a dictionary:

```
>>> l=['A','B','C']
>>> di={'A':3,'V':3,'M':7,'B':6,'D':2,'C':1}
```

I am forming a look-up key by extracting the values and appending with a '~'

```
>>> '~'.join(str(di.get(key)) for key in l)
```

Since this key would form the core of the search  - I needed to confirm that it will always return the same string.
Nothing in my test so far reveals otherwise.
Any fore-warning would be useful.

Comment: As you're iterating over the list not dict so the order is always going to be the same.

Comment: So lists do not have the problem that dicts suffer from - pretty much like java then

Comment: Yes, lists are ordered collection. Python’s lists are really variable-length arrays.

Comment: As ``.get`` returns a ``None`` object (unlike Java) if the key is not in the dictionary, you might end up with strings like "3~None". Consider using ``.get(key, my_default)`` or ``[]`` (which throws a ``KeyError``).

Comment: If you are on Python 2.7 and above [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) will solve this problem for you nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will produce results that always occur in the same order, unless you change your list.  Sets and dicts are unordered, and even if they appear to have an order you can depend on, they don't.  There is a definite order, you just can't count on it being one you expect -- In Python 3.3, for example, the order changes every time you start the interpreter, because a salt is added to the hash.

However, tuples and lists have a defined order.  Unless you change the list or replace the tuple with a different one, the keys you are using will always be in the same order.

What you've written is equivalent to:

```
result = []

# l has a consistent order, so the result will be in the order of l
for key in l:
    result.append(str(di.get(key)))

'~'.join(result)
```

..it will fail with a TypeError if the value in the list is not a key in the dict, so you won't ever get strings like "3~~1", either.

Comment: This will fail even if the keys are defined, as OPs dict values are ints.

Comment: To be precise, dicts and sets *do* have a defined order, which matches the hashing algorithm . ie. if hash randomization isn't on, then a given dict (not only a given instance, but any equivalent copy) will always return items in the same order. The order is fixed - it's just not an order that a human easily comprehends (like alphabetic or insertion order).

Comment: Good point, however, you cannot count on that order, because the hashing algorithm could potentially change -- as indeed it has in python 3.3, where the order will change every time you start the interpreter.

Comment: @kampu: that's not quite true.  You can have two dictionaries which are equal to each other but have different iteration orders -- IOW, insertion history matters too, not merely the hash of the values.

Comment: @BrianVisel : interesting, last I checked that was turned off by default, but now (3.3.1) it's on by default.

Comment: *nod* since 3.3, I think -- although this changelog could be an overview of all 3.3.x changes.. 
http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, this is what you need:

```
 '~'.join(str(di.get(key)) for key in l if di.get(key) is not None)
```